# LVL Beam for basement

Tags: basement

I’m working on finishing my basement and would like to take down the walls and open up my stairs.  The existing wall is load bearing (pic attached).  I have trusses(?) that are 16” wide that are being held up by the wall.  Directly above is my living room.  My question is what size lvl beam would I need to replace the wall?  The length is 15 feet of wall that I’d like to take down.  Thanks.

Comment: I do not see a picture.

Comment: talk to a structural engineer ... it makes no sense to be asking here because your question is not answerable without a structural assessment

Comment: Are you sure it is load bearing wall, unusual for a basement, usually a beam with posts supporting it.  If it is load bearing, you will need proper supports before even thinking of removing the wall, which requires an engineer to design.  Too weak or wrong placement is not good.